# MFC EditText unicode text changes to multibyte characters

Tags: c++, mfc

I am converting a legacy MFC program to support unicode. I can build and run the program now. However, when I input unicode text into an EditText control, this happens:

[image: This is when I am inputting text.]

The above is when I am inputting text.

The below is after the focus leaves the EditText.

[image: After]

Now, the second text is the multibyte conversion of the first text which I do in the code. What I don't understand is that in all the places I see, the program only uses `SetWindowText` function. And everywhere that is used, I've made sure that the text is converted from multibyte to unicode. However, this makes me think I missed something.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Perhaps a callback I should be looking at?

Comment: Given the first screenshot, I'd assume that the application is already supporting Unicode. So, you don't have to do anything to "support Unicode". If you convert it to multibyte and call `SetWindowText()` on the Unicode text, then I'd suppose it would then display the converted text. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Why are you converting Unicode to multibyte ?

Comment: What you are really doing is, you are using a string that's Unicode already (encoded using UTF-16), convert it to a multibyte version (looks a bit like UTF-8, but could be ANSI), and then throwing that MBCS string at a control that understands UTF-16 only. Why did you assume, that this wouldn't break in some way?